# problematic javascript array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I'm having problem with my javascript. When running as a html functions of the buttons do not work.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>
<button id=“buttonOne” onclick=“myFuntion()”>Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button id = “ButtonTwo” onclick=“myFunction()”>Count the Number of products!</button>

<p id=‘demo2”></p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "mango", "orange","avocado"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

var buttonOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var buttonTwo = document.getElementById("buttonTwo");

buttonOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fruits = fruits.sort();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
});

buttonTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    length = fruits.length;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = length;
});
```

If someone could take a look at this and perhaps suggest what is wrong with it?

Comment: Remove `onclick=“myFuntion()”`. There is no *myFuntion* or *myFunction*.

Comment: You have the wrong types of quotes in your HTML. Use `'` or `"`, not `“` and `”`. Turn off "smart quotes" in your text editor when editing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id = “ButtonTwo” onclick=“myFunction()”>Count the Number of products!</button>
```

var buttonTwo = document.getElementById("buttonTwo");

the id is B and the getElementById is b change one of them

And myFunction doesnt exists